# Add application icons to Plasma 5 panel?

Tags: kde, plasma

In KDE4 there was an option to add to panel by right clicking an application icon, like so

[image]

In Plasma 5 there's only an option to add to favorites

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### First of all, widgets mustn't be locked!

---in order to be able to make such changes!

:)

---

In newer versions of Plasma 5 (like 5.12), we have two options - "Add to panel (Widget)" and "Pin to Task Manager" - when right-clicking an application icon from the *Application Launcher* menu:

[image]

So, there are two ways of having launchers available on the panel, in both KDE4 and Plasma5.

- First, by adding **a shortcut inside the Task Manager widget**. (It also works with the 'Icons-only Task Manager widget.)

This can also be done by opening your application and right clicking on it in the Task Manager, then select the option "*Show A Launcher When Not Running*" (renamed "*Pin*" in later versions).

[image]

- Second, by getting **a separate launcher in the panel** (a launcher *widget*: outside the Task Manager widget); in KDE4 this was done with the 'Add to Panel' option, which was absent is some early versions of the 5.x Plasma series: at which point
  that could be done anyway by draging & dropping desktop file launchers (like those in `/usr/share/applications`) onto the panel.

[image]

[image]

But, as I said, we do have the two options available when right-clicking an application icon in the menu, at least in the current 5.12 version of Plasma.

---

[Dolphin shortcut in the task bar ? | KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=127638)

Comment: The second part doesn't seem to work for me. Do you mean drag it into the panel itself (as opposed to a plasmoid within the panel)? The existing plasmoids do not move aside, and no icon is created.

Comment: @Sparhawk - In fact the KDE4 option is not related to the Task Manager, it creates icons on the panel. In Plasma 5 it works for me to get the same result by drag&drop from usr/share/applications onto an area between the left application launcher ('Start' button) and the Task Manager - all that in Plasma 5 (on Manjaro). I also tested that in KDE4 (same as the 'Add to panel' option).

Comment: @Sparhawk - added animated gif

Comment: Ahhhh…I was stupid. I had widgets locked. Thank you.

Comment: What are the relative advantages of "add to panel" and "pin to taskbar"?

Comment: I think something changed (Plasma 5.23.4), I can no longer drag icons from the launcher menu to a panel, unlocked or not. The context menu option still works, but if you have two panels and want to add icons to the *other* panel, without a menu, it gets weird. Either create a new menu in the second panel and then delete it, or add icons to the first panel, then drag them to desktop, and then you can finally drag them to the second panel.